is there any command in MySQL that similar to Compute By in SQL server
I'm learning MySQL, and I see that in the book of SQL, they used SQL Server and they have this command 'Compute by'
The query:
SELECT khoa. `ma khoa`, `ten khoa`, COUNT (`ma lop`) AS 'so lop'
FROM khoa, lop
WHERE khoa. `ma khoa` = lop. `ma khoa`
GROUP BY khoa. `ma khoa`, `ten khoa`

This provides us with the total number of classes for each department
However, we cannot determine the specific classes included in each department from the above query result.
they use Compute by
SELECT khoa. `ma khoa`, `ten khoa`, `ma lop`, `ten lop`
FROM khoa, lop 
WHERE khoa. `ma khoa` = lop. `ma khoa` 
ORDER BY khoa. `ma khoa` 
COMPUTE COUNT (`ma lop`) BY khoa. `ma khoa`

So, is there any way that I can do it in MySQL

Why are you learning MySQL from SQL Server books?

Please create a fiddle to demo the case.

You should check GROUPING SETS, COMPUTE clause is no longer supported

"they used SQL Server and they have this command 'Compute by" How old is the material you are reading? COMPUTE BY was removed from SQL Server in 2012. The last version to permit that syntax was SQL Server 2008 (R2)

Agreed, why are you learning MySQL from an old SQL Server book? This is a bit like trying to repair a Tesla Model 3 by reading a Ford Capri manual. You have all the tutorials and documentation on the internet at your fingertips - you don't need an outdated book about the wrong product.

@ADyson Repairing a modern Ford Fiesta from a Ford Capri might be a better comparison :-)

Not to mention as well: Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs That the book also isn't using ANSI-92 JOIN syntax suggests you're reading a book from the early 90's... It honestly sounds like it's 20 or more years out of date.

Anyway, just use GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (khoa.[ma khoa], khoa.[ten khoa], khoa.[ma lop], khoa.[ten lop]), (khoa.[ma khoa]) )
